# jquery click on link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After an event is triggered, how do I make jQuery click on a link with an `id` of `mylink`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#lol').click(function() {
   $('#mylink').trigger('click')
   return false;
});
```

replace `click` with your event.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `click()` without any parameters triggers the event, instead of registering an event handler for it.

```
$('#mylink').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
window.location = $("#mylink").attr("href");
```